# How to add information to a marker on the map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map with markers on it, how to add information to them?

I'm using OverlayItem thing.

I found [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons), but I'm almost sure that I have seen somewhere solution created by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on how much information you need per marker. You can for example set the title of each marker, and you can even display that as text over the marker if you want to. Additionally you can even use `snippet` which is another attribute of overlay items. Personally, I use the `title()` and `snippet()` attributes very often when using maps, but if you need to display more detail, you should go with @Michal's answer of using pop-up balloons for each overlay.

There are quite some posts on pop-up balloons if you're interested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707923/show-popup-above-map-marker-in-mapview) , [here](http://www.anddev.org/drawing_popup_balloons_above_mapitems-t9454.html) and [here](http://deckjockey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-baloon-display-on-map.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: well I kind of need to display more details, but to be honest I can't find anything about InfoWindow overlay on android, I "locate" something interesting in the first "here" of your answer. I mean @Kieran's post about using popUp view, but still I have a problem with implementation.

Comment: have a look at the 3rd link. Detailed tutorial on what you want.

Comment: public class BaloonLayout extends LinearLayout {

    .......

u see this? I can't compile it. Well of course without ...... part, but still I'm getting " no suitable constructor found for LinearLayout() " Is there anything I should put before the dispatchDraw method?

Comment: do you have this import- import android.widget.LinearLayout;? And did you create the constructor?

Comment: is there any chance to chat via msn or sth like this?

Answer (score 0):

Which google api are you using? You can put the additional info as an InfoWindow overlay (you can include html there too). And on a marker click show the infowindow with an appropriate content (e.g. html content).

Comment: Api level 6, platform 2.0.1, can You give me an example of InfoWindow Overlay?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the code anymore. I worked on something like this long time ago...

Answer (score -1):

You can basically use any Drawable to put as a marker on the screen. This includes your own made Drawables. Then you can simply use an ItemizedOverlay to show your Drawables on the map.

To your custom drawable you can draw any information in the draw()-method of the Drawable like I did in my Drawable here:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    marker.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, null, new Rect(-38, -102, 38, -28), null);
}
```

Comment: I have this puting maker on the screen, the thing I don't know is how to add information after clicking on point/ marker

Comment: Can't you just add the information to the Drawable and then invoke a redraw of the map? With the onTap-Method of the Overlay you know which marker has been touched.