# Show marker annotation on ANdroid maps

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, popupwindow

i'm looking for a hint/way to show an annotation when clicked on a marker. I've extended ItemizedOverlay to show the marks and implemented onTad(int index) to react when a marker is tapped. Now i want to pop up a little windows as there is for iphone ([example](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/01/19/google-maps-marker-clickable-button))...
I'v found the android-mapviewballoons, but it doesn't satisfy my requirements, since it centers the map and popups in the middle of the screen.
I found another lib ([example2](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)) which would be the best solution, since i can create a layout in xml and inflate it, but it requires a VIEW in order to attach the popup at the right position....but in the map i have only GeoPoints. I understand that is not applicable, since the position of a view is related to the screen, and the marker position is related to the coordinates of the map...

My idea was to create another ItemizedOverlay for the popupWIndow and let it point to the same coordinates of the tapped mark (geopoint).

Comment: did you check the answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707923/show-popup-above-map-marker-in-mapview

Comment: Hi,, initially i didn't understand the example. The revisioning it again it was clear and i successfully implemented it into my project. Thanks