# Add Legenda to OSMdroid mapview with Pop-Up

Tags: android, menu, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have a map with custom tiles and I need to add an optional legenda to the site explaining the color code of the custom map.

I have now tried to achieve what I want by triggering a toast showing an image via a menu. But now I learnt that toast is only displaying 3.5 seconds max, but I would need something that stays overlayed onto the map until it's being tapped onto. Thus also does not disappear as the map in the background is being moved.

EDIT: Here is my attempt to use an pop-up. But once I click the menu the app "unfortunately stops".

Here's my menu:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    //..
        case R.id.legenda:
            showLegenda();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And this is how my popup looks right now.

```
private void showLegenda() {
    // TODO Add popup here
 /*   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastlegenda,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1));

    Toast toast = new Toast(this);
    toast.setView(view);
    toast.show();*/

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
               this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
               inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastlegenda, null, false), 
               100, 
               100, 
               true);
            // The following line raises the error:
            pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.mapview), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

}
```

Here is map_layout.xml where my R.id.mapview is coming from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is mapview not possible as root container for a popup? The mapview is part of a tabview. Would be great if someon could give me a hint what raises the error here.

Here's the toastlegenda.xml (stemming from an earlier attempt to have an agenda with toast)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Test"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black">
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/dcmr_legenda_bl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Test 1,2, 1,2..."
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the entire error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15404): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at nl.sense.demo.MapActivity.showLegenda(MapActivity.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at nl.sense.demo.MapActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MapActivity.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:969)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(15404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: so what is the error?  Stacktrace?  or do you get an ANR? What is the xml for the R.layout.toastlegenda

Comment: @Ifor the error is a java.lang.NullPointerException - I added the whole error and the xml above.

Comment: So the one thing you pass in that could be null is the result of find view.  Check this.  You should also have the source for popupWindow.java somewhere with your SDK install (may not be the right version though) so you can go and look at the offending line.  Debuging from a stack trace is a skill you need to learn

Comment: i was wondering if it is not possible to combine showatlocation with a mapview. it's osmdroid.   <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
     android:id="@+id/mapview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>