# How to open a phoning pop up on clicking a maps marker in android?

Tags: android, popup, google-maps-markers

I try to open a pop up whith the choice of 2 phone number when clicking on a marker on maps.

I try to follow instructions here :

[Show popup above map marker in MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707923/show-popup-above-map-marker-in-mapview)

but ItemizedOverlay method doesnt work.

here is my onmarker onMarkerClik :

```
    gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

            // Open a pop up with phone number to call

            return true;

        }
    });
```

What can I put in it to have my pop up ? to have this :

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What kind of popup do u need?do u need a popup in which u can select the way of calling application use?is that so ? Correct me if i m wrong.if possible post the screenshot...it vl help alot...

Comment: It's a pop up who put 2 phone number for exemple '123' and '456'.
it can be call with the default phone app.

it look like this :
http://imgur.com/DFaMWfS

thank you for your help !

Comment: You can use **linkify** to make the calls directly onclicking the mobole number.....

Comment: Once search about linkify in android u vl be getting everyrhing..if that is the thing u r searching for tell me know i vl send u all the code in here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it by showing the contacts that have a phone number registered :

```
    gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

            Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
            pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts with phone numbers
            startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

        return true;

    }
});
```